# Most efficient way to store unused chunk of data in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, database-design, database-performance

There are few columns in a table and about 100+ columns based data, which only need to be stored for later export to another sources.

This data (besides the first few columns mentioned) doesn't need to be indexed / filtered or be manipulated in some sort. There are no queries, that can check this data in any way.

The only thing, that application layer can retrieve the whole row with additional unused workload and deserialize it for further conversion in external format.

There was an idea to serialize whole class into this field, but later we realized, that it's a tremendous overhead for data size (because of additional java class metadata). 
**So it's a simple key-value data** (keys set is static as the relational model suggests).

What is a right way and data type to store this additional unused data in PostgreSQL in terms of DB performance (50+ TB storage)? Perhaps it's worth to omit key data and store only values as array (since keys are static) and get values after deserialization by index at the application layer (since DB performance on the first place)?

Comment: Use a `jsonb` column for a simple key/value store. It has the added benefit that the data will be compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), thanks a lot, but `jsonb` is really tricky data type.

In terms of required amount of bytes for single tuple, that contains `jsonb`, one must always keep in mind - the size of `key` names in `json` format.
Such that, if someone want to reinvent the wheel and store large `key` names as single `byte` indexes - it will decrease overall tuple size, 
but it isn't better than storing all data as typical relational table fields, because `TOAST` algorithm applies for both cases.

Another way is to use `EXTERNAL` storage method for single `jsonb` field.
In that case `PostgreSQL` will keep more tuples in cache, since there is no need to keep whole `jsonb` data in memory.

Anyway, i ended up with combination of `protobuf` + `zlib` in `bytea` field type (since there is no need to query data in `bytea` field in our system) :

[Uber research for protobuf + zlib](https://eng.uber.com/trip-data-squeeze/)